# How do I know how many pages my manuscript will make in kindle ebook format?

Tags: kindle, epub, independent-publishing

I am planning to write a book. I will be using LibreOffice writer for that. After completing the work I will make a pdf file and import it in kindle. But what I want to know before hand is the number of pages it will create in kindle. Is there anyway to do that? I want to have a less than 150 page kindle ebook. Does anyone know the average number of words a kindle page contain?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DON'T - PDF is not a good ebook format - PDF is for describing how to print a document. Please use an HTML derived format e.g. epub (or Amazon kfx) so that I as a reader can alter the font size and scroll as I read. PDF tells me you don't want me to read it. So the number of pages depends on how I read the book - on a Kindle or on a computer which have different numbers of lines per page and it depends on how ill I am as to what size of font I have.

Comment: @mmmmmm Thanks friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to validate the average number of words per page or the total number of pages in an eBook beforehand but there is a method to find how many pages we will end up with, in our eBook. Just use the Kindle Previewer tool. Alternatively, you can also use the Online Previewer tool within Amazon KDP. I'd recommend the desktop version (Kindle Previewer) as it offers more options, comparatively.

**Remember**: even if you find out that your eBook comes to a specific number of pages while previewing, it will vary in the real-world, for your readers. That's because every person's ereader device (or mobile phone) and their Kindle settings will be different. Different font face, font size will all make it almost impossible to exactly predict the number of pages our eBooks will have.

All we can do is deduce at a range of page numbers that we may end up with, using different font options within the previewer tool.